# How to Pass Insert Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I have created a TCP server. When request comes, server parsed that data and pull mac_address from that data. According to mac_address Mysql query SELECT a row from Terminal Table and push data to Report Table with that mac_address and the data.

The problem is;

If request mac_address is not in Terminal Table, INSERT query still insert data with the last received mac_address that Terminal Table includes.

I'm expecting when server receives data with undefined mac_adress, it should tell;

```
console.log('Error while performing SELECT Query.');
```

Main Program:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
socket.setEncoding('utf8')
socket.on('data', function(data) {
var reqdata = JSON.parse(data);
connection.query('SELECT * FROM terminal WHERE mac_address=?', [reqdata.mac_address], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = rows[i];
      finaldata = {
        mac_address: row.mac_address,
        factory: row.factory,
        coop: row.coop,
        machine: row.machine,
      };
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Error while performing SELECT Query.');
  }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO report SET ?', finaldata, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("RESULT : INSERTION OKAY");
      console.log("\n" + "END" + "\n");
    } else {
      console.log('Error while performing INSERT Query.');
      console.log("\n" + "END" + "\n");
    }
   });
   });
  });//socket.on
 socket.pipe(socket);
});//createServer
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Thx, I fixed it.